# Can't create table (errno: 150) while trying to create a new table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

On PHPMyAdmin, I entered into the database I am using, then selected SQL tab, and entered:

```
CREATE TABLE PianoDS
(sid CHAR(20),
cid CHAR(20),
grade CHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (sid,cid),
FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Studenti);
```

but I obtain

> 1005 - Can't create table 'basi_di_dati.PianoDS' (errno: 150) (Dettagli...)

Comment: Turning on "Mind reading v0.1alpha", reading what `Studenti` is. Failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define to which column your foreign key relates, not only the table

```
CREATE TABLE PianoDS
(
  sid CHAR(20),
  cid CHAR(20),
  grade CHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (sid,cid),
  FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Studenti(id)
);
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69f12/1)